# Store a variable for a future script run, Python

Tags: python, loops, variables, break

I have a script that loops through file names in a json doc. In the event that there are no more filenames, I have a break statement that breaks the loop and stores the last read filename in a variable to print. Is there a way to save this variable so when I call the script again, it can use the last read filename as the starting point?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could save it to a dotenv file or use configparser to save it to a ini and then retrieve it the same way.

To write just do

```
with open('yourfile.ini', 'wb') as config:
    config.write(yourvariable_info)
```

This is a snippet I had to retrieve variables:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

def config(filename='/home/pi/your/directory.ini', section='postgresql'):
    # create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()
    # read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to postgresql
    db = {}# retrieves a dictionary
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db
```